# Can a variable be null and not null at the same time?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I am running Delphi XE3 with SQLmemTable (Windows 7). I got an error

`Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (Integer)`

and traced the error to this line of code using the 2nd record in the table.

`hh:=tblPop['HHINCOME'];`

I checked the 2nd record of the table for empty fields but found nothing. I then tried the following code:

```
var 
q:variant;
zz,s:string;
hh:integer;
……
q := tblPop['HHINCOME'];
s:=vartostr(q);
  if VarIsNull(q) then
    zz := 'q is a null variant '+s
  else
    zz := 'q is not a null variant '+s;
ShowMessage(zz);
hh:=Strtoint(s);
```

The message returns that `q` is not null and it returns an integer value for `s` but I still get the the same error message when I convert `s` to an integer on the last line. If I comment out the line

> `// hh:=Strtoint(s);`

and replace it with a static value

> `hh:=3;`

the program executes without error.

How is it possible for a variable to have a value and to be null at the same time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: since you're not running a quantum computer, i'd say no ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `StrToInt()` is also failing means the string does not represent a valid integer value.  Maybe there is whitespace in the string.  Maybe the represented value exceeds the bounds of an `Integer`.  Hard to say, since you did not show what the actual string value is.

Comment: The value in the field is between 1 and 5. I have replaced the values of the 1st 10 fields in the table (there are 318) by hand and there are no white spaces. The strange thing is that the 1st record succeeds but the program constantly fails on the 2nd record.

Comment: Without seeing the ACTUAL STRING DATA, there is no way to confirm that. If the string value were valid, `StrToInt()` would not be failing. So something is wrong with the content of the string.

Comment: My apologies for wasting your time - there is no question like that to start with. I found the problem way down in the code in the form of an erroneous table filter that resulted in an empty table on all values for `hh` except `hh:=3`. That is why the 1st record succeeded but the 2nd one failed. Thank you for your input - it got me thinking out of the rut.